# V8 JavaScript engine "String" to substring

Tags: c++, v8

Is there a V8 C++ function to create substrings directly from existing string handles, or do I have to invoke a script call to do this?

The work-around is currently to use "->Write()" to dump the string, then store the sub part into a new string.  I just wanted to know if there was another way.

Thanks.